# Python double while loop not working, can't figure why

Tags: python

I understand that maybe with the use of "for" the code could be clear, but I would like to understand why this code isn't working.
Also, the code is an adaptation for a 2008 MIT OCW class exercise in which the only functions that are allowed for use are the arithmetic ones, if, elif, else, print and while.
Just to point it out, the code was supposed to print out the first 1000 prime numbers.

```
print '2, '      #Print the prime 2 to set only odd primes.
primesofar=3     #Set 3 as the first prime
primecounter=1   #Mark 3 as the first prime to test until 1000, otherwise the while below should test to 1001
primesupport=1   #Create primesupport with a integer value
while primecounter<1000:
    primesupport=primesofar/2  #Create a support counter for test the prime. This counter only had to have the half value of the supposed prime, because we only need to try to divide by the primes that are lower than the half of the suppposed prime. In fact it would be better to test for values that are lower than the square root of the supposed prime, but we can't use square root operation yet.
    while primesupport>0:
      if primesofar%primesupport == 0:
        primesupport=-1       #If the remainer of the division is 0, the number isn't prime because it will have more than two divisors so we set primesupport as -1 to exit the while and increase the current primesofar to the next odd number.
        primesofar=primesofar+2
      elif primesupport==1:   #If primesupport is 1, we tested all the numbers below the half of the supposed prime which means the number is prime. So we print it, set the while exit and increase the number of primes counted and go to the next odd number.
        print primesofar+', '
        primesofar=primesofar+2
        primesupport=-1
        primecounter=primecounter+1
      else: 
        primesupport=primesupport-1
```

I am thankfully for the fast responses and now I think that maybe there was a break in the code that I can't see. Because of this, I will try to write down what I think that the code was supposed to do in order to make it easier for you to point out where I am making a mistake.
Let's start:
primesofar receives 3; primecounter receives 1 and primesupport receives 1.
The first while test primecounter and since primesupport is less than 1000, it enters the loop.
Then, primesupport value is changed to 1 because 3/2=1
Since primesupport is greater than 0, it enters in the second while loop.
The if condition is true (3%1=0) so the code enter the if, change the primesupport to -1 and increase primesofar by two.(now primesupport=-1 and primesofar=5)
Here is has a problem because it leaves without printing 3, but let's continue.
When it goes back to the second while it will receive a False, since -1 is not greater than 0.
That will make the code test the first while and since primecounter was not changed, it will enter the loop again.
Primesupport will now receive 2 (because 5/2=2)
It will enter the second loop and pass throught all of it until the else condition.
Primesupport will be decreased by one( primesupport now =1) and the while loop will continue  entering in the elif now.
That will print 5
increase primesofar to 7
decrease primesupport to leave the while loop and increase primecounter, going back to the first loop and start again.
I confess that besides the 3 that is not being printed as expected, i can't see where i am making a mistake here. Hope you could point me out.

Thank you all for the help, especially FallenAngel, John Machin , DiamRem and Karl Knechtel for pointing out the error and by showing a debug method.

Comment: it get stuck and i must to ctrl+c it probably to end some infinite loop

Comment: also, are you sure your indentation is correct? more specifically, is the line `primesupport=primesofar/2` indented correctly within the first while loop?

Comment: @Sensato sp Did you debug it? Which loop is affected? What are the values of loop variables?

Comment: Or maybe `primesupport=primesofar/2` is non-integer?

Comment: @ Kshitij: yep, indentation is right, I just made it manually here to appear right in the code box.

Comment: @Howard, still learning how to make very basic programs, don't know how to debug yet. However, I changed the first while control to < 3 in order to test if it wasn't a speed time and still got stuck in the program, it prints the "2, " and don't make anything more.

Comment: @KshitijMehta: I thought that the "/" operator would give me the integer result of a division, did I understood that wrong?

Comment: the `/` operator is fine; it'll give you the integer result

Comment: however, i'm not sure i understand your algorithm. why don't you just use the sieve algorithm?

Comment: You may try with `while primecounter<5: instead of `while primecounter<1000:` so you see initial results, and increase `primecounter` while loop amount to check if your logic is correct...

Comment: @FallenAngel I tried <3 and it still get stuck

Comment: "I understand that maybe with the use of "for" the code could be clear" More importantly, it would be *easier to get correct*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel unfortunately, as stated, the use of for is not allowed and the only way I was able to thought was with the double while. :-(

Comment: What do you mean "not allowed"?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the issue:

you got stuck because primesofar=3 and in python 3/2 = 1, so in if primesofar%primesupport == 0: this is True because 1%1 = 0 in python and in the code of that if primesofar is 1+2, then primesofar is again 3 and you jump from a while to another in the eternity.

Comment: I think I saw a problem now, because it will not print the 3 as a prime because of what you write, but in the first line of the if will set the primesupport to -1, won't that end the second while loop after leave the if?

Comment: yes ends the second if but sets primesofar to 3 again so the division 3/2 it repeats.

Comment: No, primesofar was not altered in the if (it still has 3) and it will be incremented by two in the end of the if (going to 5 and starting again). Unless the if isn't getting the two operations...

Comment: If primesofar is 3 and primesofar%primesupport = 1%1=0 the code jumps from the first while to de second while to the if and to the fist while...

Comment: Now I am not sure if I understand. I will try to write what I think that the code will do and I would really appreciate if you could point where I am wrong. To me, the code will enter the first loop with primesofar=3 primecounter and support =1. when it makes support=sofar/2, sofar will get 1. The code will enter elif and print 3, increase sofar, decrease support and increase counter, leaving the second while and proceding to test 5, am I wrong in this?

Comment: You mean "support will get 1". Then `sofar % support` is `3 % 1` which is `0` -- it **doesn't** "enter elif"

Answer (score 1):

```
if primesofar%primesupport == 0:
    primesupport=-1
```

When the code gets to this point, the inner loop will be broken without `primecounter` changing. The code will repeat the same steps with the same `primecounter` value, and necessarily get to the same point; there is no way to break the outer loop.

(Although the correct way to break out of a loop is to use `break`.)

Comment: In this point it has to leave the if without change primecounter because the number it found is not a prime, it will need only to increment primesofar by 2. Maybe the if is only processing the first line and don't getting the primesofar=primesofar+2?

Answer (score 1):

I place some `print` statements and this is the output that your program gives:

```
primesupport 1
primesofar 5
primesupport 2
primesupport 1
primesofar 7
primesupport 3
primesupport 2
primesupport 1
primesofar 9
primesupport 4
primesupport 3
primesofar 11
primesupport 5
primesupport 4
primesupport 3
primesupport 2
primesupport 1
primesofar 13
primesupport 6
primesupport 5
primesupport 4
primesupport 3
primesupport 2
primesupport 1
primesofar 15
primesupport 7
primesupport 6
primesupport 5
primesofar 17
primesupport 8
primesupport 7
...
```

Your code never enters `elif primesupport==1:` block, so `primecounter` never increases...

What is used for testing is :

```
while primecounter<2:
primesupport=primesofar/2
print 'primesupport %s' % primesupport
while primesupport>0:
    if primesofar%primesupport == 0:
        primesupport=-1 
        primesofar=primesofar+2
        print 'primesofar %s' % primesofar
    elif primesupport==1:
        print primesofar+', '
        primesofar=primesofar+2
        primesupport=-1
        primecounter=primecounter+1
        print 'primesofar %s' % primesofar
        print 'primesupport %s' % primesupport
        print 'primecounter %s' % primecounter
    else:
        primesupport=primesupport-1
        print 'primesupport %s' % primesupport
```

Reason is, final `else` block decreases `primesupport` up to 1, then in the next loop, `if primesofar%primesupport == 0:` returns true and that block is executed, you increase `primesofar` by 2 and start a new prime number check...

Comment: Thank you very much not only for showing my error but by showing me a debug method also. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for `primesupport == 1` BEFORE you test for `primesofar % primesupport == 0` because `any_integer % 1` is always 0, and the code that you want to execute when `primesupport == 1` just isn't happening.

When you fix that, you will see that `print primesofar+',` won't work ... you should be able to fix that yourself.

The most elementary effective debug techniques that you can deploy are (1) use a small set of data so that you can comprehend what is going on, and you can check the results with no more than a pencil and a piece of paper (2) print out what is happening.

(1) `while primecounter < 5:`

(2) After the 2nd while,

`print "sofar, support, count", primesofar, primesupport, primecounter`

Comment: Thank you very much for showing my error. Putting the primesupport == 1 condition first solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that every time primecounter gets to 1, you are checking if primesofar%primesupport == 0, and it'll always do. So your program never enter the elif and the else part. thus prime counter never get increment. So it'll be a infinite loop.

You can check this by putting a print statement after if primesofar%primesupport == 0:

```
if primesofar%primesupport == 0:
    print primesofar
```

You can correct it by check primesupport==1 before you check primesofar%primesupport == 0 :

```
print '2, '      #Print the prime 2 to set only odd primes.
primesofar=3     #Set 3 as the first prime
primecounter=1   #Mark 3 as the first prime to test until 1000, otherwise the while below should test to 1001
primesupport=1   #Create primesupport with a integer value
while primecounter<1000:
    primesupport=primesofar/2  #Create a support counter for test the prime. This counter only had to have the half value of the supposed prime, because we only need to try to divide by the primes that are lower than the half of the suppposed prime. In fact it would be better to test for values that are lower than the square root of the supposed prime, but we can't use square root operation yet.
    while primesupport>0:
        if primesupport==1:   #If primesupport is 1, we tested all the numbers below the half of the supposed prime which means the number is prime. So we print it, set the while exit and increase the number of primes counted and go to the next odd number.
            print primesofar
            primesofar=primesofar+2
            primesupport=-1
            primecounter=primecounter+1
        elif primesofar%primesupport == 0:
            primesupport=-1       #If the remainer of the division is 0, the number isn't prime because it will have more than two divisors so we set primesupport as -1 to exit the while and increase the current primesofar to the next odd number.
            primesofar=primesofar+2
        else: 
            primesupport=primesupport-1
```

this code will print 1000 primes for you.

And by the way, you can't connect a str and int with a +. you can just print the prime. Print statement will add newline automatically.

Comment: Thank you for pointing my error. Changing the primesupport condition to the first check solved my problem.